# Meteor HTTP.GET get gzipped json back how to decompress?

Tags: meteor

```js
var url = "https://www.parsehub.com/api/v2/projects/{PROJECT_TOKEN}/last_ready_run/data";
        var api_key = 'te79WidrkOmN_Fxs2e_kNnX5';
            url = url.replace('{PROJECT_TOKEN}', 'tbNBvhG208xhGUpecAk62V80');
            console.log('start fetching remote results from ' + url);
            this.unblock();
            HTTP.get(url, {params: {api_key: api_key}}, function(error, result) {
                if(error) {
                    console.log('http get FAILED!');
                } else {
                    console.log('http get SUCCESS');
                    if (result.statusCode === 200) {
                        console.log('Status code = 200!');
                        console.log(result.content);
                        
                    }
                }
            });
```

The result.content here is gzipped, how to unzip it? I tried gb96:zlib but could not make it work. Also is there a hidden flag while using HTTP.get to automatically unzip the gzipped response?

I also put this issue on meteorpad at http://meteorpad.com/pad/8LnKNnzusSNhzbQ5s/Leaderboard

To reproduce, just select a player and click "Add 5 points".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Sorry I know this is a really late response and the question has been open forever, but I have a solution.

In your `Http.get` options you can pass `npmRequestOptions` as an object. In this object use `gzip : true` and your response should be decompressed for you.

Something like this...

```
HTTP.get("http://something", {
    "npmRequestOptions" : {"gzip" : true}
}, 
function(err, res) { 
    //response is decompressed! 
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to get back data with application/zip header set and using the npmRequestOptions isn't working. Is there documentation for the npmRequestOptions I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: @mikeLspohn I found the github update where it was [added](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/commit/8dae78d48b80d7dab9154d912102a9ebb0a28f60) and it's listed in the [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/http_call). It's not much but I hope it helps!

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
Run Command:

npm install unzip

fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip').pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: 'output/path' }));
```

Or pipe the output of unzip.Parse() to fstream

```
var readStream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/archive.zip');
var writeStream = fstream.Writer('output/path');

readStream
  .pipe(unzip.Parse())
  .pipe(writeStream)
```

Comment: I was able to use curl with gunzip to get the true json out, now the question is Meteor.http.get will get the gzipped content back. I now need to find out a way to gunzip the content back to json string. Your answer seems to be for node.js but not for meteor.